# jQuery toggle() prevents loading of image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to jQuery and found the toggle function really attractive. I wanted an image to switch to different image after a click and back again, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#expand").toggle(function(){
        $(this).attr("src","images/expandWidget.png");
    },function(){
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minimizeWidget.png");
    });
}); // end ready
```

And the image itself is declared like this:

```
<img id="expand" src="images/minimizeWidget.png"></img></div>
```

I notice that when I ran this through Chrome, the image changed to:

```
<img id="expand" src="images/minimizeWidget.png" style="display: none;">
```

And my image did not show. Why did Chrome do that? If I instead change the toggle to click(), my image shows without a problem and I can switch to a different image, but not back of course. I have no errors in the console and the page doesn't import other styles that would affect img. Am I using the toggle incorrectly? Please let me know if you need more information.

Thanks

Comment: This is wrong: `<img id="expand" src="images/minimizeWidget.png"></img>` Img tag uses the "self - closing" : `<img id="expand" src="images/minimizeWidget.png" alt="" />`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `toggle` use `.click()`

<kbd>**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsbin.com/avehiw/2/edit)**</kbd>

```
var images = ["images/expandWidget.png", "images/minimizeWidget.png"], c=0;
$("#expand").click(function(){
    this.src = images[++c%2];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You've misunderstood what jQuery toggle does.

It 'toggles' the visibility of an element, hence it disappearing. It's not the greatest name admittedly, but we all used to have to write our own version of the toggle method inside `.click()`.

See the documentation:

http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

You probably want something like:

```
$("#expand").click(function(){
    if($(this).attr("src") == "images/expandWidget.png") {
        $(this).attr("src", "images/minimizeWidget.png");
    } else {
        $(this).attr("src","images/expandWidget.png");
    }
});
```

Comment: It depends on what version of jQuery OP is using. The syntax that you saw in the original post is valid for pre-1.9 versions.

Comment: hmm I tried your code and that worked. Thanks! I am using jQuery 1.9.1. So that has been fazed out?? I read a book which used the example I gave. The only thing I would change is the call to this twice by storing in a temp variable but I can manage that :)